# .NET MVC 4 nested list data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I'm a beginner with ASP.NET MVC.

I want a nested list in a view.

In the picture "MENÜLER" is a product group and other datas are products of product group.

So I want to list products by products group.

How to do this can anyone explain me?

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: For what I'm getting, you want to do a `.GroupBy` then just loop through the data in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fixed ;

```
Public Class ProductGroup

    Private _GroupID As String
    Public Property GroupID() As String
        Get
            Return _GroupID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _GroupID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _TopGroupID As String
    Public Property TopGroupID() As String
        Get
            Return _TopGroupID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _TopGroupID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _RestaurantID As String
    Public Property RestaurantID() As String
        Get
            Return _RestaurantID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _RestaurantID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Products As List(Of Product)
    Public Property Products() As List(Of Product)
        Get
            Return _Products
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Product))
            _Products = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

this is my product class

```
Public Class Product
    Private _ProductID As String
    Public Property ProductID() As String
        Get
            Return _ProductID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _ProductID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Price As String
    Public Property Price() As String
        Get
            Return _Price
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Price = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
```

EF query :

```
Public Function ListProductsByGroups(ByVal RestID As Integer) As IList(Of ProductGroup)
        Dim groups As List(Of ProductGroup) = (From g In db.TBL_URUN_GRUP
                         Where g.RestoranID = RestID
                         Select New ProductGroup With
                                {.GroupID = g.GrupID,
                                 .Name = g.Isim,
                                 .RestaurantID = g.RestoranID,
                                 .TopGroupID = g.TopGrupID
                                    }).ToList()

        For Each item In groups
            Dim products As List(Of Product) = (From p In db.TBL_URUNLER
                                              Where p.GrupID = item.GroupID
                                              Select New Product With
                                                     {.Name = p.Isim,
                                                      .Price = p.Fiyat
                                                    }
                                                     ).ToList()
            item.Products = products

        Next
        Return groups

    End Function
```

And View :

```
 @Code
            For Each item In ViewBag.Products

        @<div class="box">
                <div class="title">@item.Name</div>
            @For Each products In item.Products

                     @<div class="column1-1">
                        <div>
                            <div class="left">
                    <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="content/images/Icons/plus.png" />
                     <input type="text" value="1" class="textcenter" style="width:20px" />
                                </div>
                           <div class="productlist left"> @products.Name <span>Çok taze tavuk eti ile marulun eşşisz uyumu</span> @products.Price</div>
                        </div>


                         </div>

                Next

            </div>

                Next

   End Code
```

Comment: This is a suboptimal solution for MVC.

Comment: What is the optimal solution  can you explain me ?

Comment: Firstly rather than using a foreach, you should use view templates, one for IEnnumerable products hen one for products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dropDownList. Code is better than a long speech so for sample:

You have the burger type :

```
public class Burger
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

The code for populate the dropdownlist :

```
public static SelectList GetBurgers(int index)
{
    List<Burger> burgers= new List<Burger>();

    burgers.Add(new Burger() { ID = 1, Name = “Chicken” });
    burgers.Add(new Burger() { ID = 2, Name = “Bicky” });
    burgers.Add(new Burger() { ID = 3, Name = “BigMac” });
    SelectList selectList = new SelectList(burgers, “ID”, “Name”, index);
    return selectList;
}
```

From the Index action method, let’s add the select list object to the ViewData dictionary and request the view to be rendered;

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["burgers"] = GetBurgers(1);
    return View();
}
```

Right-click on the method you’ve just coded and select Add View;
Create a form using the Html helper method BeginForm and add a dropdownlist and a submit button. It seems like :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
<%= Html.DropDownList(“lstBurgers”, ViewData["Burgers"] as SelectList) %>
<input type=”submit” value=”Post” />
<% } %>
```

You have to create now an action method that will handle the post when the user clicks the post button:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection forms)
{
    int selectedItem = Convert.ToInt32(forms["lstBurgers"]);
    ViewData["burgers"] = GetBurgers(selectedItem);
    return View();
}
```

You can create a dropDownList for each type of products. For the doc you have many tuto and documentation about MVC 4 and the differents controls : http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4

Hope this help you !

Comment: thanks for answer. But i dont want use dropdown list. Example http://s30.postimg.org/xlceyw2xt/image.jpg